# What is the difference between Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

What is the difference between [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: This must be a duplicate, if not a FAQ!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is gathering close votes as `Not Constructive` - it's got a definite answer and isn't a rant.  Downvotes are perhaps understandable due to lack of research effort but still in my opinion a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the site for questions about a real, actual programming problem you're facing. Meta Stack Overflow, on the other hand, is the site for questions *about* Stack Overflow.

Hence, you've actually asked this question on the right server. ;)

At the top of each [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is a link to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), which describes the purpose of each site, what kinds of questions are on-topic, and what kinds of questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Look at FAQ of both [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Stack Overflow is Q&A site for professional and enthusiast programmers where you can ask questions about programming problems, software algorithm etc.

Meta Stack Overflow is for bug reports, feature requests and talk about the Trilogy and Stack Exchange sites.

Look at [the blog about Meta Stack Overflow.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/)